# Failed to create thumbnail, removing original

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm trying to take a picture with the built-in camera application.
When I take pic with the normal cam, everything ok.
But When I take pic with the "selfie cam", I get this error :

```
 Failed to create thumbnail, removing original
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:836)
at com.spg.movil.util.ImageUtils.saveImageToExternalCacheStorage(ImageUtils.java:94)
at com.spg.movil.RutaActivity$SavePic.doInBackground(RutaActivity.java:841)
at com.spg.movil.RutaActivity$SavePic.doInBackground(RutaActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The line which get a NPE is:

```
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),                   (String)file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
```

I debugged and none of the parameters are null...

When I debug, in MediaStore.class, I see code entering into :

```
public static final String insertImage(ContentResolver cr, Bitmap source,
                                               String title, String description)
```

instead of

```
public static final String insertImage(ContentResolver cr, String imagePath,
                String name, String description)
```

I tried to cast the second parameter to string, but it still enter in the method with bad signature...

Any idea???

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, did you ever figure out the solution

Comment: No, I never figured it out, but I used the sample from google, and the code works, so it kind of resolved the issue.

Comment: url of that sample code pls ?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/
otherwise, it is easier to download it with your SDK Manager. you can open it in android studio with File > Import Sample > Camera 2 Basic